# Unit testing an async method which invokes DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM Light 5.2 in visual studio 2012. My unit tests are MS tests and I can't figure how to test my async methods, as the DispatcherHelper doesn't invoke my Action. 
Using the following test, the Thread.Sleep is never reached in debug.

In MVVM Light sources DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUi calls UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(action), and nothing never happens.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
        TestedMethod();
        // Do assert here
    }

    void TestedMethod()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            // Do stuff
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
            {
                // Do stuff
                Thread.Sleep(1); // Breakpoint here
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it can help, as I didn't want to modify MVVM Light sources, I finally wrote a proxy on DispatcherHelper which directly invokes the action when it is initialized in a test method. It also handles the design mode.

I juste had to search/replace every DispatcherHelper by UIDispatcher, and that's it.

here is the code :

```
public static class UIDispatcher
{
    private static bool _isTestInstance;

    /// <summary>
    ///      Executes an action on the UI thread. If this method is called from the UI
    ///     thread, the action is executed immendiately. If the method is called from
    ///     another thread, the action will be enqueued on the UI thread's dispatcher
    ///     and executed asynchronously.
    ///     For additional operations on the UI thread, you can get a reference to the
    ///     UI thread's dispatcher thanks to the property GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading.DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The action that will be executed on the UI thread.</param>
    public static void CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(Action action)
    {
        if (action == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if ((_isTestInstance) || (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic))
        {
            action();
        }
        else
        {
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(action);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     This method should be called once on the UI thread to ensure that the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading.DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher
    ///     property is initialized.
    ///     In a Silverlight application, call this method in the Application_Startup
    ///     event handler, after the MainPage is constructed.
    ///     In WPF, call this method on the static App() constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isTestInstance"></param>
    public static void Initialize(bool isTestInstance = false)
    {
        _isTestInstance = isTestInstance;
        if (!_isTestInstance)
            DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///    Resets the class by deleting the GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading.DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher
    /// </summary>
    public static void Reset()
    {
        if (!_isTestInstance)
            DispatcherHelper.Reset();
    }
}
```